# Debugging sigsegv faulting Apache

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-http-server, segmentation-fault

What's the best way to get meaningful gdb backtraces from Apache server which misbehaves on production?

```
 [Tue Aug 02 16:07:12 2011] [notice] child pid 27681 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

It's probably some Apache module doing bad things, but I need symbolic gdb traceback to get started debugging what and where.

- How to enable debug symbols for Apache on Ubuntu
- How to extract one and only one core dump from Apache child
- How to reopen this file in gdb

Ubuntu 8.04 / Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [configure an Apache web server for core dump on segmentation faults](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/configure-apache-web-server-for-core-dump.html).

You might also have to set core dump size limit to unlimited in `/etc/security/limits.conf`:

```
*    hard    core    unlimited
```

Log in, check that core size is not limited by saying `ulimit -a` and restart apache.

To analyze the core file, start gdb:

```
gdb /usr/lib/apache2/mpm-worker/apache2 /path/to/core.dump
```

gdb command `bt` prints out the stack trace.

Comment: I also had add line * soft core unlimited

Comment: Also for Ubuntu the gdb command was: gdb /usr/sbin/apache2 /tmp/apache2-gdb-dump/core